# Orientation issue in iPad ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I check the orientation of the device in `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` and  force the orientation by calling `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method.

```
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     [super viewWillAppear:YES];
     _levelComplete = YES;

     [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] duration:0.01];

   }

 - (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
  {
      if (toInterfaceOrientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) )
     {

     }
     else  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
     {

     }
 }
```

**The problem i face is that `toInterfaceOrientation` is remains 0 for both  `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` method hence program crashes.**

What might be the problem?

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad
       {
         _levelComplete = YES;

        [self adjustViewsForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

       }
    -(void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
   {

      if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        }
 }
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks :)
Problem is with [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned : The problem i face is that toInterfaceOrientation is remains 0 for both viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear method hence program crashes.

The orientation 0 refers to unknown orientation. Set the break point on `viewWillAppear` and `viewDiddAppear` and on orientation delegates. Note that do the delagates of orientation gets called first of the view delegates.

You can use the delegate

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Using this delegate and the application will be present in Landscape mode or any desired orientation mode.

Try it.

Comment: Your code forces landscape mode even when the device is in portrait mode.

Comment: yes. You can provide any orientation inside the delegate which is required. You can even force Portrait mode if required.

Comment: I want to Change view orientation based on device orientation! i dont want to force a single orientation.

Comment: Yes. It will will force the orientation which is required. You can get the present orientation through interfaceOrientation property of self class..

Comment: Also the orientation 0 generally comes in simulator. Not on device.